# Android studio 2.12 - out-of-the-box App Widget - "Error Launching Activity"

Tags: android, widget

I was developing an android Widget, which was functional, if not finished. Android Studio proposed an upgrade, but my version was too far behind, so I had to download the whole studio, not a patch. When installing, it left me no choice but to delete the previous version while installing.

When trying to install my widget on a device, after the installation succeeded, this message came up :

```
Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity
```

After googling, and failing to find a solution, I decided to create a new project (android 2.3), create a new App Widget (right-click package > new > widget > app widget), and not change a single line of code.

I get the very same behaviour as with my own package.

I have tried at various times to "Invalidate Cache / Restart"; currently I am investigating gradle of which I know next to nothing. In the course of this, I clicked some things (in my memory, right-click > properties, on some file), but I can't find it again, which opened a window which proposed something close to "default behaviour > launch activity / do nothing / other choices... ". This might well do the trick.

Can someone point me to this found and lost dialog box?

Comment: The dialog box I was looking for was "Edit Configurations", in the toolbar right between the build and run buttons. I chose "Launch Options > Launch nothing" which got me this error : InstantRunPushFailedException, then explored this dialog while I was there, clicked completely unrelated things : "clear log before launch", "skip installation if APK has not changed" (unchecking it) and "Use same device for future launches", which solved my problem. Does anyone have a clue, so I don't die stupid? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Approch 1 :**

If you see that error occur after upgrading your IDEA, upgrading Android Studio version. you may need to refresh the IDE's cache.so go through below way.

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

**Approch 2 :**

Make sure that you have this structure in your `Manifest.xml` file. just check out.

```
<activity
        android:name="FULL_NAME_OF_YOUR_ACTIVITY"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity
```

Comment: I did that several times, sadly to no avail.

Comment: My *Widget* does NOT have this intent; I also mentioned this was a widget related question, right out in the title.